# Multi-platform JADE

Tags: java, agents-jade

I'm trying to generate more instance of Jade on the same host. I know that it is possible through cmd line but I'm not able to do it with some java code. I can't run the command line in Java because, in this way, I can lost some information about the platfomr... Anyone can help me?
Below my code and the error:

```
public class MainCMD_ {

static String classAgentName= "Agents.MyAgent";
static int agentNum=6;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String platformHost= "localhost";
    String platformName="Platform_";
    int platformPort= 2000;


    for (int i =1; i<3;i++) {
        platformName="Platform_"+i;
        while(!isAvailablePort(platformPort)){
            platformPort++;
        }

        //new jade.Boot3(new String[] {"-local-host",platformHost,"-local-port",Integer.toString(platformPort),"-name",platformName,"-gui"}); 
        genPlatform(platformHost,platformName,platformPort);

        System.out.println("Platform "+platformName+" created!"); 

    }
}


private static void genPlatform (String platformHost, String platformName, int platformPort) {

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.instance();

    ProfileImpl profile = new ProfileImpl(); 

    profile.setParameter(Profile.PLATFORM_ID, platformName); 
    profile.setParameter(Profile.LOCAL_HOST, platformHost); 
    profile.setParameter(Profile.LOCAL_PORT, Integer.toString(platformPort)); 
    profile.setParameter(Profile.GUI, "true");
    profile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN, "false");
    //profile.setParameter(Profile.CONTAINER_NAME, "MainContainer");
    //System.out.println(profile.getProperties());

    ContainerController cc = runtime.createMainContainer(profile);  

    AgentController ac;

    for(int i = 1; i<agentNum;i++) {
    try {
        ac=cc.createNewAgent("MyAgent"+i, classAgentName, null);
        ac.start();

    } catch (StaleProxyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}


private static boolean isAvailablePort(int port) {
    //metodo per verificare che la porta sia disponibile

        ServerSocket ss = null;
        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            ss.setReuseAddress(true);
            ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
            ds.setReuseAddress(true);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.close();
            }
            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Console

```
set 15, 2018 5:56:06 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFORMAZIONI: ----------------------------------
This is JADE 4.4.0 - revision 6778 of 21-12-2015 12:24:43
downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
set 15, 2018 5:56:06 PM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize
INFORMAZIONI: Listening for intra-platform commands on address:
- jicp://192.168.1.100:2000

set 15, 2018 5:56:06 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl init
 AVVERTENZA: Automatic main-detection mechanism initialization failed 
(Error setting up multicast socket - Caused by:  Can't assign requested 
address). Mechanism disabled!
set 15, 2018 5:56:06 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFORMAZIONI: Service jade.core.management.AgentManagement initialized
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFORMAZIONI: Service jade.core.messaging.Messaging initialized
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFORMAZIONI: Service jade.core.resource.ResourceManagement initialized
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFORMAZIONI: Service jade.core.mobility.AgentMobility initialized
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.BaseService init
INFORMAZIONI: Service jade.core.event.Notification initialized
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.mtp.http.HTTPServer <init>
 INFORMAZIONI: HTTP-MTP Using XML parser . 
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.messaging.MessagingService boot
INFORMAZIONI: MTP addresses:
http://mbp-di-mauro:7778/acc
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
INFORMAZIONI: --------------------------------------
```

as you can see here start the Platform 1

```
Agent container Main-Container@192.168.1.100 is ready.
--------------------------------------------
Hello, I'm  agent
I'm going to ... 
Hello, I'm  agent
I'm going to ... 
Hello, I'm  agent
I'm going to ... 
Hello, I'm  agent
I'm going to ... 
Platform Platform_1 created!
Hello, I'm  agent
I'm going to ... 
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFORMAZIONI: ----------------------------------
This is JADE 4.4.0 - revision 6778 of 21-12-2015 12:24:43
downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager initialize
INFORMAZIONI: Listening for intra-platform commands on address:
- jicp://192.168.1.100:2000
- jicp://192.168.1.100:2001

set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl init
AVVERTENZA: Automatic main-detection mechanism initialization failed         
(Error setting up multicast socket - Caused by:  Can't assign requested 
address). Mechanism disabled!
set 15, 2018 5:56:07 PM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
GRAVE: Some problem occurred while joining agent platform.
jade.core.ProfileException: Can't get a proxy to the Platform Manager -
```

here the error

```
Caused by:  Wrong platform name Platform_1. It should be Platform_2
at jade.core.ProfileImpl.createPlatformManager(ProfileImpl.java:529)
at jade.core.ProfileImpl.getPlatformManager(ProfileImpl.java:442)
at jade.core.ProfileImpl.getServiceManager(ProfileImpl.java:456)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.init(AgentContainerImpl.java:347)
at      
jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:494)
at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
at MainCMD_.genPlatform(MainCMD_.java:55)
at MainCMD_.main(MainCMD_.java:33)
Nested Exception:
jade.core.IMTPException: Wrong platform name Platform_1. It should be     
Platform_2
at jade.imtp.leap.CommandDispatcher. 
setPlatformManager(CommandDispatcher.java:231)
at jade.imtp.leap.CommandDispatcher. 
registerSkeleton(CommandDispatcher.java:731)
at jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager.exportPlatformManager 
(LEAPIMTPManager.java:198)
at jade.core.ProfileImpl.createPlatformManager(ProfileImpl.java:518)
at jade.core.ProfileImpl.getPlatformManager(ProfileImpl.java:442)
at jade.core.ProfileImpl.getServiceManager(ProfileImpl.java:456)
at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.init(AgentContainerImpl.java:347)
at 
jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:494)
at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
at MainCMD_.genPlatform(MainCMD_.java:55)
at MainCMD_.main(MainCMD_.java:33)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MainCMD_.genPlatform(MainCMD_.java:61)
at MainCMD_.main(MainCMD_.java:33)
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one MainContainer per JVM. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know this... my intent is that to have more than one Platform in one pc to simulate communication through MTP protocol suggestions? Do you think that it is theoretically possible?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question: yes, it is possible.

Assuming that you work with Eclipse, you could have two (or more) [Run Configurations](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm). Each configuration should differ by the argument section (corresponding to the args array in your main method). With the arguments, you should be able to distinguish the platform and its configuration.

As the `Runtime.instance();` access indicates, JADE platform handling via code is realized by a [Singleton](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples). Thus, you will not be able to have more than one JADE platform in one JVM. Using the above approach, each Run Configuration would produce one JVM and you really can send ACL-Messages, instead of moving messages in a platform (JADE won't serialize/ deserialize messages, if you are sending messages between agents in the same platform).

Hope this helps!